# How do I filter files of which I am a codeowner in a pull request?

Tags: github, github-codeowners

If a GitHub PR modifies files that belong to many teams, how can each team filter the change list with only the files owned by that team?

GitHub shows the messages:

> [person] requested review from team/A, team/B and team/C as code owners

The "code owners" phrase is a link to a CODEOWNERS line. But it only links one entry of one of the teams.

How can I find out **all** the files **one particular** team needs to review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the "Files changed" tab, in the file filter: select "Only files owned by you".

[image]